# CMake configure_file replace ON/OFF with 1/0

Tags: cmake

Suppose I have two libraries `ABC`, `XYZ` and two variables `ABC_FOUND` `XYZ_FOUND` in `CMakeLists.txt`. In a `config.h.in` file, I have the following lines

```
#define __USE_ABC__ @ABC_FOUND@
#define __USE_XYZ__ @XYZ_FOUND@
```

If I do `configure_file(config.h.in config.h)`, the output `config.h` file will be changed to

```
#define __USE_ABC__ ON
#define __USE_XYZ__ OFF
```

My question is how can I convert the `ON`/`OFF` options into `1`/`0`, in other word, my desired output `config.h` should be

```
#define __USE_ABC__ 1
#define __USE_XYZ__ 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `ABC_FOUND` to either `0` or `1` with

```
#cmakedefine01 @ABC_FOUND@
```

Use an intermediate variable in either environment to change it to `USE_ABC`.

Answer (score 0):

Likely, you should use [#cmakedefine](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/configure_file.html) instead of hard defines (see examples e.g. [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/qalculate/qalculate-kde4/ci/master/tree/config.h.cmake~))

But please remember that in the case of `#cmakedefine` you get a configuration header where "enabled features" (in terms of CMake `if()` command) are `#define`-d to a supplied value, while "disabled features" are `#undef`-ined. So you should test them not with `#if <something>` but rather with `#ifdef <something>`.